# How to get a callback from google maps in Android application, when navigation is complete

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-activity, google-maps-markers

I am building an android application, that will show certain points on google maps, for which I have (lat,lang) for all the points shown, with me. Whenever, a user clicks on one of these locations on google maps, I am starting a new Google Maps intent which shows navigation to the user and is supposed to take the user to that (lat, lang).

```
//suppose this function is called on onclick of google maps event
    function onclick(){
            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=32.885240,-96.763475");
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
    }
```

This will start the navigation for the user.
Now what I want to achieve is this -
Whenever this navigation is complete, I want some kind of flag to be passed to my android application, so that my application knows that the navigation has been finished.

If it is possible to automatically close the google maps application after the navigation has been completed, it will be nice to have.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks. Anyone has any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the ***finish()*** method on the activity when the destination is reached. So here are the steps that you need to implement in your program.

- First of all know the destination coordinates from the user input and pass it in the Direction API.

  ```
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=API_KEY
  ```
- When you know the destination coordinates you can pass that when the marker representing that is clicked in the navigation intent. (which you have already done)
- Make use of the location listener interface that tracks the current location coordinates.
- Put an ***if...else*** condition  where you check that the current location is equivalent to the destination.
- When the current location == Destination make a call to ***activity.finish()*** which will finally close the maps activity hosting.

Hope that Helps!!

Comment: Ohkay. So there is no way in which I can know from Google Maps application whether it has finished navigation or not? As per you approach, I will have to constantly make call to Locations API. I was kind of trying to avoid that. Because it will require more usage of network data from the clients phone.

But if nothing else works, yours seems to be an appropriate approach.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to get Location using Location Services, as explained in this tutorial - http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

And my Location is null. Any help please?

Comment: how to call `finish()` method in the activity which started as an `Intent`?

Comment: @user4909407 i have same question.did you found any solution for this?