# after initiating google maps for navigation from your app Is there any callback method when destination is reached?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, navigation, gps

I am opening google maps application from my app using implicit intent for navigation.
I want to know that if there is a way to send back a flag to my application from google maps when destination is reached.
[How to get a callback from google maps in Android application, when navigation is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443532/how-to-get-a-callback-from-google-maps-in-android-application-when-navigation-i)

I did get an answer on this from above question but again its by checking onLocationChanged function that I do not want to use. Reason I think for that is that I will duplicating most of the task that is already being done by google maps resulting in consuming more battery and resources.

Is there any action called at destination reached which I can implement in my app to initiate an activity or any other way to get a flag back to my app..?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a geofence and add it to location services. It will notify you (callback) when a user enters or exits in a particular geofence.

> Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest.  To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude.

Try to read this documentation: [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to avoid creating my own location service in my app and checking if user's current location has entered into a certain geo fence. Instead I wanted google maps to return me a flag once destination is reached as google maps is already running a location service of its own and on that if I run mine then I think it will not be optimal for the battery. Please correct me if I am wrong